# How can I multiply each element of a list by the first element, then the second element, and so on, making a list for each set of products?

Tags: ocaml, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently trying to create a list of lists in OCaml using a single list, where each new list contains the set of products resulting from multiplication of each list element by the first, second, third, and so on, list element. I should also say now that I'm only allowed to use ´List.hd´, ´List.tl´, and ´List.nth´.

An example would be:

```
[-1, 1, -1, 1] -> [1, -1, 1, -1]

                  [-1, 1, -1, 1]

                  [1, -1, 1, -1]

                  [-1, 1, -1, 1]
```

I've created a function that does this perfectly fine, but my issue is that it only does so for the very first time, as every additional time it destroys the head of the list and does it for the new smaller list. I need help making it so the list isn't getting destroyed as I do this.

Here is my code that implements the multiplication and appends the result as a list in the list of lists:

```
let rec hopTrainAstate = function (astate) ->
 if((astate == []))
    then []
    else multiplyAll(List.hd astate, astate)::hopTrainAstate(List.tl astate);;
```

Here is my code for the multiplication:

```
let rec multiplyAll = function (head, alist) ->
 if((alist == []))
    then []
    else (head *. List.hd alist)::multiplyAll(head, List.tl alist);;
```

Here is the result of using the function with the example above:

[[image: output]

As you can see, the multiplication is working just fine, but it's working on a list that keeps removing the head. I am pretty new to OCaml so maybe this isn't as hard as I think it is, but I haven't been able to find anything online that has helped. I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Please post code samples in text form, not images. Text is easier to read (more accessible), and SO has excellent code formatting features which you can use. Also, if you're working with lists, look at the `List` module, there are lots of helpful functions in there: https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html . Particularly look at `List.map`

Comment: @Yawar Thanks for the feedback. I've added my code in text to make it easier for people to help. Also we aren't allowed to use List.map, only List.hd, List.tl, and List.nth.

Comment: @DawsonJBaileyYou shouldn't post images of ANY text. Text is perfectly accessible as plain text. It can be copied, pasted, read by a screen reader and indexed by search engines. Images do none of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main function is working with smaller and smaller lists, so this is more or less the expected result.

It would probably help if your main function had a second parameter that represents the whole list. That's what you need to be passing to your multiplication function.

If you don't want your main function to have an extra parameter (which is reasonable) then you could write a helper function. In fact, a helper function inside the main function could easily access the initial list directly.

If you're just starting with OCaml, you might not know what a helper function is. It's a function that's used inside the main function to help with the computation. For example if I want to find the maximum element of a list of non-negative ints, I could write this:

```
 let find_maximum l =
     let rec imax max_so_far il =
         match il with
         | [] -> max_so_far
         | hd :: tl -> 
             if hd > max_so_far then imax hd tl
             else imax max_so_far tl
     in
     imax (-1) l
```

It's fairly common to have a recursive helper function inside a non-recursive main function. This allows the recursive function to have extra parameters.

Note that in this example the helper function `imax` could access the original list under the name `l` if it was interested in this value.

Comment: I suggest you rewrite your main function with a helper function that does what the main function does now. The new main function will just call the helper function. You should immediately see what the real code should look like.

Comment: We actually aren't allowed to use nested functions at all, although I do appreciate your help and I do understand how it would work if I was allowed to do it that way. we can only use List.hd, List.tl, and List.nth.

Comment: We are allowed to make other functions that aren't nested to help, if that would also be a possible solution to this.

Comment: Sure, you can use an additional function that has the second parameter.

Comment: Ok so I made a new function to try and help me figure all of this out. My new function is exactly the same, except with a new parameter "bstate" which takes in the same list. I put bstate as the second parameter in my multiplyAll function in main (rather than using astate). This is giving me the same issues as before. Did you mean to do something like that and I'm just messing it up or did you mean something else entirely?

Comment: You need to be able to access the full original list to pass to the multiplication function. You don't want to pass smaller and smaller lists as is done in your code above. Note that `astate` is a smaller list at each call. You want the *original* value of `astate` from the first call. You can set this up many ways. I would suggest making a new function that acts exactly like your main function except it has an additional parameter. Then rewrite your main function to call this function like this: `f astate astate`. But I don't want to write your code for you.

Comment: Ok so it turns out that I just made a really stupid mistake. I copy pasted hopTrainAstate to make the new function you helped explain to me, which I called hopTrainAstate2. In the new function I had forgotten to add the 2 at the bottom when it calls itself and doing so fixed everything and I am now getting the correct input. Thank you so much for your help!!!